# Long-deleted image shows up in error log. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-log

This is the error message I am trying to figure out where it is being generated. This happens also with other non-existent files.

I have tried to search the database for attachments with non-existent file and what I've found I deleted from the database, but these messages keep coming. I looked for code that might generate this error, but I didn't find anything.

Yes these files are missing from the server, and that is fine. They have been deleted a long time ago.

How can I find what is generating this error?

`2023/11/22 08:39:33 [error] 1687#1687: *1253339 open() "/www/mydomain/public/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/my-image-11.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 40.111.21.45, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2019/12/my-image-11.jpg HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mydomain.com:15846"`

Comment: This is the uploaded image url, which stored in your database.

Comment: How did you search the database? If your site is using a page builder, it can be difficult to get accurate search results because of how page builders sometimes store data.

Comment: 90% of the site is custom built without a page builder.  I searched wp_posts content, wp_posts attachment title, wp_meta and did a full db search as well. Some images were manually deleted a long time ago from the server. I created a script checking all attachments on the site if the file they point to exists and ran that until nothing more was found.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a web server log file entry, not a php debug.log entry.

It says a browser or some other http client running on a machine at IP address `40.111.21.45` requested that nonexistent file. Could that image still be referenced in a post or page somewhere in your site?

If you look at your web server access log, you should see an entry that goes with this one. The access log probably shows the so-called "referer", the URL of the page that requested the image.

Comment: I checked the access log and there was no referer that goes with this.
``

Comment: the error: [link](https://snipsave.com/user/krisztiantoth/snippet/PwgRBmysnEZI21YCAO/)